# Why do I have Policy Violation even though API Level 33 Compliance is Complied since August 25, 2023

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, google-play, google-play-console

How are you? May I seek why Google Play Console has informed me I am violating policy regarding API Level 33?

This has been complied since August 25, 2023 which is version 7.0.4 currently in production. I updated config XML file. By the way, this has been developed using Ionic Framework 4 based on AngularJS.

Please see attached images for the details needed. Thank you for your generous answer, input and kind consideration.

[Policy Violation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSQvO.jpg)

[Releases Overview 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qce1C.jpg)

[Releases Overview 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmOLW.jpg)

[Google Play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4qAv.jpg)

Please check android-targetSdkVersion in config XML file. See that it's 33.
[config.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bzkq.jpg)

Comment: Please share the file where you defined the targetSdkLevel/compileSdkLevel of your application. As stated by Google in one of the screenshots you shared, you need your application to target API level 33.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @tomerpacific, please check updated body. It has screenshots of the files. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have the policy Violation in your closed and open testing tracks.
You must grant that all your tracks are updated with your app version that has API Level 33 set in targetVersion.